# iPhone VS ipad development process (differences and similarities)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am new to iOS development. I am trying to figure out these things.

1. A project both in iPhone and iPad. what things are same for both (coding, graphics or UI)?
2. Design Pattern of apps are same or different?

waiting  for answer
Thanks :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Personally, I find that the only real difference between the iPhone and the iPad is the `UI` and `UX`. Most of the code is the same for both applications. (In fact, you can even reuse a lot of code if you are doing a universal app!)

The main difference really is the screen size. The iPad is huge in comparison to the iPhone, and this difference gives you a lot more options to work with.

Another thing to note is that the iPad is usually done in landscape orientation, whereas the iPhone is done in portrait. This is not an absolute rule however, it's just the way I see it.

The graphics aren't too different between the devices, except that because of the large screen size, you can do a bit more detailed work with the iPad images then the iPhone images. (Even with the retina display, too fine detail on the iPhone is barely noticeable.)

The other thing I wanted to mention is the flow of the devices. Again, because of the screen size of the iPad, you can fit a lot more content on the screen, and therefore have to push to new views less frequently. I've worked on apps where we had 3 `UIViewController`'s for the iPhone version, and only 1 for the iPad version.

In short, it depends really on your type of app. If you have a lot of content, and want to display it all at once, go for the iPad. If you want a streamlined, minimal approach to your app, go for the iPhone.

Again, this is all just my personal opinion. Hope that Helps!

Comment: Thanks MSgambel for your suggestion. I further need to know one thing that if I want to use images rather than built in buttons and labels then what should I do?

Comment: Try `buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];`, then `[button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];`, and that will set your custom image to the button. To use the pressed down buttons image, use `UIControlStateHighlighted`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use native controls without much theming and customization on the iPhone. But iPad is a bigger beast. Users use your iPad app for a longer time. iPhone apps are used for a short stint and then closed, used again for a short stint and so on.

Analytics published by Flurry showed that the average time an iPhone app is kept open is about 1.2 minutes. Design and develop it in a way that data is available as fast as you can.

iPad apps are used in a relaxed setting. While I don't have the numbers, it's probably used more often and for a longer time than an iPhone app. Themes and custom UI elements do matter a lot there

Second, iPad apps need to be supported on all orientation (or at least a minimum of two orientations)